# What module environments do/don't support using require() to load JSON files?

Tags: json, node.js, requirejs, amd, browserify

node.js supports `require()`'ing JSON files.  For example, a `data.json` like this:

`{"bar": "abc", "baz": 123}`

... can be used in node.js like this:

```
var foo = require('./data.json');
console.log(foo.bar); // --> "abc"
```

My concern is that this doesn't appear to be a documented part of CommonJS and, thus, may not be supported in other module environments (like Browserify?)

Thus, my questions: **What module environments do/don't support this? I.e. is this a generally acceptable practice?**